# How to access a database entry in a row with Scala Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I am using the code from the following tutorial: 
sysgears.com/articles/building-rest-service-with-scala/#16

My database schema:

```
    /**
     * Customer entity.
     *
     * @param id        unique id
     * @param firstName first name
     * @param lastName  last name
     * @param accountBalance account balance
     * @param birthday  date of birth
     */
     case class Customer(id: Option[Long], firstName: String, lastName: String, accountBalance: Int, birthday: Option[java.util.Date])

     /**
      * Mapped customers table object.
      */
     object Customers extends Table[Customer]("customers") {

       def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

       def firstName = column[String]("first_name")

       def lastName = column[String]("last_name")

       def accountBalance = column[Int]("account_balance")

       def birthday = column[java.util.Date]("birthday", O.Nullable)

       def * = id.? ~ firstName ~ lastName ~ accountBalance ~ birthday.? <>(Customer, Customer.unapply _)

       implicit val dateTypeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[java.util.Date, java.sql.Date](
       {
        ud => new java.sql.Date(ud.getTime)
       }, {
         sd => new java.util.Date(sd.getTime)
       })

       val findById = for {
         id <- Parameters[Long]
         c <- this if c.id is id
       } yield c
     }
```

I am writing a function that retrieves a Customer with a specified id number. And then I want to access this Customer's account balance and perform calculations on it.

This is the code I have so far:

```
     def withdraw(id: Long, amountToWithdraw: Long): Either[Failure, Customer] = {
         try {
           db.withSession {
            val customerRow = Customers.filter{ a => a.id === id}
            var amount = customerRow.accountBalance
             if (amountToWithdraw < accountBalance){
                accountBalance -= amountToWithdraw
                    update(customerId, customer)
                Right(customer)
             }
             else{
                 Left(insufficientFundsError(id))
                }
          }  
         } catch {
           case e: SQLException =>
             Left(databaseError(e))
         }
       }
```

When I try to run it, I get an error though:

```
    value accountBalance is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Query[com.sysgears.example.domain.Customers.type,scala.slick.lifted.NothingContainer#TableNothing]
    var amount = customerRow.accountBalance
                             ^
```

So I suppose my problem is I don't know how to access database entry accountBalance for the specified customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did't actually need to extract any customer. I just needed to extract the value of accountBalance of customer with a specified id. This is how I did that:

```
    val accBal = Customers.filter{ a => a.id === id}.map(_.accountBalance).firstOption
```

And because accBal is of type Option[Long] I had to:

```
    val accBalAsLong: Long = accBal.getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slick works like Scala collections. `Customers` is like a collection. I does not have a member  `accountBalance`, only its elements have that. So you have to use `.map`. Or in your case it is probably easier to fetch the customer record right away.

`val customerRow = Customers.filter{ a => a.id === id}.run.head`

Comment: Thank you.
Ok, so this is my code now:
var customerRow = Customers.filter{ a => a.id === id}.map(_.accountBalance)
var amount: Long = customerRow - amountToWithdraw
I am getting an error:
value - is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Query[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Long],Long]
Can I not perform operations on the extracted value accountBalance?

Comment: Customers is a query, something like a collection. It is NOT a row. Your variable name is misleading. As a comparison, a List[Customer] does not have a method accountBalance. Only the customer object contained in it have that. The line I suggested executes the query and  gives you the first customer in the results, which is what you probably want. Also read the Slick documentation, it should make things clearer. General hint: Do think Scala collections when using Slick. Do NOT think SQL. It has a different API than Scala collections.